# How to use a variable inside a variable in conky

Tags: conky

I have a file when the line 15 has the full path to an icon. That said, I want to display that icon using the **${image}** variable:

```
${image myImage.png -p 0,10 -s 50x50}
```

To get the line value, I would use sed:

```
${exec sed -n '15p' $HOME/.Shell/Conky/ConkyWeather/dataWeather.txt}
```

My question is, how can I do both things together? My current code is not working.
I tried:

```
${image ${exec sed -n '15p' $HOME/.Shell/Conky/ConkyWeather/dataWeather.txt} -p 0,10 -s 50x50}
```

And:

```
${image exec sed -n '15p' $HOME/.Shell/Conky/ConkyWeather/dataWeather.txt -p 0,10 -s 50x50}
```

So, how can I make a variable work inside a variable and call **exec** inside **image**?
Btw, if you know any other way to read the line and insert into image, it will do as well.

Comment: The nesting in your 1st example seems to be wrong: `${image ${exec sed -n '15p' $HOME/.Shell/Conky/ConkyWeather/dataWeather.txt} -p 0,10 -s 50x50}`

Comment: I'm not sure how to nest variables in conky. I couldn't find anywhere explaining how to do it. It's problably wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess it was copy/paste. I changed the } to fix the example

Comment: So, it doesn't work like that either, right?

Comment: No. I checked only the $ {exec} expression and it's working fine.
I checked only the ${image} expression and it's working fine. But if I use the exec to suplly the image file for image, nothing

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can try backticks.

```
Test backticks: ${exec echo `echo foo` bar}
```

Visual result:

[image: conky command with backticks]

From the above result, you may try

```
${image `sed -n '15p' $HOME/.Shell/Conky/ConkyWeather/dataWeather.txt` -p 0,10 -s 50x50}
```